# Remove row within groups if coordinates of subgroup are within another subgroup in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

I have a dataframe such as

```
Groups NAMES start end 
G1     A    1     50
G1     A    25    45
G1     B    20    51
G1     A    51    49
G2     A    200   400
G2     B    1     1600
G2     A    2000  3000
G2     B    4000  5000
```

and the idea is within each `Groups` to look at `NAMES` where `start` & `end` coordinates of **A** are within coordinates of **B**

for instance here in the example :

```
Groups NAMES start end 
G1     A    1     50    <- A is outside any B coordinate 
G1     A    25    45    <- A is **inside** the B coord `20-51`,then I remove these B row. 
G1     B    20    51  
G1     A    51    49    <- A is outside any B coordinate 
G2     A    200   400   <- A is **inside** the B coordinate 1-1600, then I romove this B row. 
G2     B    1     1600
G2     A    2000  3000  <- A is outside any B coordinate 
G2     B    4000  5000  <- this one does not have any A inside it, then it will be kept in the output.
```

Then I should get as output :

```
Groups NAMES start end 
G1     A    1     50
G1     A    25    45
G1     A    51    49
G2     A    200   400
G2     A    2000  3000
G2     B    4000  5000
```

Does someone have an idea please ?

Here is the dataframe in dput format if it can help you ? :

```
   structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("G1", "G2"), class = "factor"), NAMES = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    start = c(1L, 25L, 20L, 51L, 200L, 1L, 2000L, 4000L), end = c(50L, 
    45L, 51L, 49L, 400L, 1600L, 3000L, 5000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible approach. We'll split the df by `NAMES` and join the two parts to each other by `Groups` to do within-group comparisons. Only `B` rows can get dropped, so those are the only ones whose row numbers we want to keep track of.

We can then just group by `rowid` to tag the `B` rows by whether or not they have any A inside them. Finally, filter to the `B` to keep and concatenate back to the A rows.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("G1", "G2"), class = "factor"), NAMES = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), start = c(1L, 25L, 20L, 51L, 200L, 1L, 2000L, 4000L), end = c(50L, 45L, 51L, 49L, 400L, 1600L, 3000L, 5000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

A <- filter(df, NAMES == "A")
B <- df %>%
  filter(NAMES == "B") %>%
  rowid_to_column()

comparison <- inner_join(A, B, by = "Groups") %>%
  mutate(A_in_B = start.x >= start.y & end.x <= end.y) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  summarise(keep_B = !any(A_in_B))
  
B %>%
  inner_join(comparison, by = "rowid") %>%
  filter(keep_B) %>%
  select(-rowid, -keep_B) %>%
  bind_rows(A) %>%
  arrange(Groups, NAMES)
#>   Groups NAMES start  end
#> 1     G1     A     1   50
#> 2     G1     A    25   45
#> 3     G1     A    51   49
#> 4     G2     A   200  400
#> 5     G2     A  2000 3000
#> 6     G2     B  4000 5000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: And what if I also whant to include when the A coordinate are inside B coordinate but not completly ? cf : for instance ```A : 120- 300``` and ```B: 150:400``` ??

Comment: I tried  : ```start.x >= start.y & end.x <= end.y | start.y <= start.x & end.y > start.x | start.y <= end.x &  end.y >= start.x```

Answer (score 2):

This will also do using `purrr::map_dfr`

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_split(Groups) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>% mutate(r = row_number()) %>%
        full_join(.x %>% 
                    filter(NAMES == 'B'), 
                  by = 'Groups') %>%
        group_by(r) %>%
        filter(any(NAMES.x == 'B' | start.x > start.y & end.x < end.y)) %>%
        ungroup %>%
        select(Groups, ends_with('.x')) %>%
        distinct %>%
        rename_with(~ gsub('\\.x', '', .), everything())
        )

#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   Groups NAMES start   end
#>   <fct>  <fct> <int> <int>
#> 1 G1     A        25    45
#> 2 G1     B        20    51
#> 3 G1     A        51    49
#> 4 G2     A       200   400
#> 5 G2     B         1  1600
#> 6 G2     B      4000  5000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I think the code still needs some improvement, will do it